# react native app continuously switching network between cell and wifi

Tags: react-native, internet-connection

I have a chat application in react native.
I am using NetInfo for connection check but i am encountering this weird issue that the connection is switching between "wifi" and "cell" automatically which results in app hang

Comment: just fix your boolean flag to offline or online

Comment: sry not didn't get your suggestion..explain plz